# JQuery click function not adding/removing class

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am trying to make a clickable image that would allow my side menu to show/hide. This works if I manually insert the class for "menu-open", however my click function will not trigger this class, I've been searching but have failed to come up with an answer, much appreciated.

This is what I have so far.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>TESTING</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,, initial scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<body  class="menu">
<header>
    <a href="#" class="menu-toggle"><img src="img/logo-white.png" width="150px"/></a>
    <nav class="menu-side">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact us">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
    <div>

    </div>

</header>   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        var body = $('body');
        $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
            $(body)toggleClass('menu-open');
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my CSS is:

```
.menu{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position: relative;
    left:0px;
}
.menu-open{
    margin-left:201px;
}
.menu-open .menu-side{
    left:0px;   
}
.menu-side{
    background-color: #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: -201px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: There should be a period in `$(body)toggleClass('menu-open');`. `$(body).toggleClass('menu-open');`

Comment: Also there's no need to wrap `body` again, it's already a jQuery object: `body.toggleClass('menu-open');`

Comment: And when that's corrected, does your code still not-work?

Comment: I added the period, however it still does not trigger the effect I intend it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var body = $('body');
        $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
            $(body).toggleClass('menu-open');
        });
    });
```

This wll toggle the class `menu-open` on `body`

Comment: Thank you, I added the $(document).ready and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a period

`$(body).toggleClass('menu-open');`

Comment: As was noted in my comment above. Please flag the question as off-topic due a typo instead of farming rep from it.

Comment: Already flagged it. Farming rep lol